# Plural Label of Managed Package Object

Tags: apex, api, controller, custom-field

I have an Object which is deployed using Managed Package in my Org.
Here is the object (Name Changed):

[image: Object]

API name of the custom object is **res__Accs__c**. Now when I tried to get the plural lable of the object in apex class as **res__Accs__r**, I am seeing an error that the API name is incorrect.

Can anyone please let me know how to get the Plural API name of Custom Object which is deployed using Managed Package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You object name should be extracted from Object Name field in your image.

So it should be `res__Accs__c` and `res__Accs__r` and not the field label and plural labels.

Both field label and plural labels are generally available when configuring Custom object tabs.

[image]

From Setup --> Quick Find --> type packages

[image]

Comment: even using res__Accs__r as my plural label, I am seeing the same error. As this is a managed Pacakge object, do i need to add any prefix to the API name?

Comment: Yes you should prefix the package namespace before the custom object API Name.

Comment: I know this may sound silly, but could you please let me know how to find the namespace of the package which is used to deploy this?

Comment: @SFDCUser I added images to my comment above. Check it out.

Comment: I am finding this strange. 'res' is the namespace of the package and I am using res__Accs__r in the query and I am still seeing the error. Wondering what is missing in the API name

Comment: It depends on how the managed package was installed. I am not sure what else could go wrong. It would be worthwhile checking the object permissions on Profile level.

Comment: the query is working for singular label i.e, res__Accs__c. Whereas, when I query using Plural lable, res__Accs__r, I am seeing this error. I have tried all the combinations as res__CustomAccounts__r, res__CustomAccount__r, nothing has worked. As a system admin, I could able to see the data but the problem is with Plural label

Comment: Also take note, you can use plural object name only from another custom object via lookup. If you just run the below which i think you are, then it will not work

`SELECT Id FROM res__Accs__c` will work but `SELECT Id FROM res__Accs__r` will not work.